# Meteor IronRouter onBeforeAction causes exception in defer callback

Tags: permissions, routes, meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze

I'm trying to secure my meteor app with `iron-router`, here's my onBeforeAction function:

```
this.route('manageUsers', {
    path: '/panel/user_management', 
    layoutTemplate: 'panel',
    onBeforeAction: function(){
        if((Meteor.user() === null)||(Meteor.user().role !== 'superAdmin')){
            Router.go('signIn');
            throwAlert('You dont have access to see this page', 'notification');
        }
    }
});
```

When I'm trying to go to `/panel/user_management` subpage by pressing a link button everything goes fine (user is redirected etc.), but when I type the path directly in my browser (`localhost:3000/panel/user_management`) and hit enter user is not getting redirected and I receive in console `Exception in defer callback` error. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

For additional information, this view lists me all users registered. When I go to this path normally (without error) I see complete user list. When I receive error template doesn't appear in `> yield`.

Comment: What does `throwAlert` method do?

Comment: it is my method for handling/showing errors (it takes two arguments: message and type of message (depends on the second argument it shows blue/green/red background color for my notification/alert box, built with html & css - it looks very similiar to bootstrap ones)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I've solved this - the problem was wrong `if` statement, here's the correct one:

```
if((!Meteor.user())||(Meteor.user().role !== 'superAdmin')){}
```